# como saber si un servicio esta en ejecucion

Tags: android-studio

Supongamos que creamos una app y creamos un servicio, este es el codigo del servicio:

```
public class Servicio extends Service {
public void onCreate(){
    super.onCreate();
    Toast.makeText(Servicio.this, "Servicio activado ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){
    Toast.makeText(Servicio.this, "onStartCommand", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return START_STICKY;
}
public void onDestroy(){
    Toast.makeText(Servicio.this, "onDestroy", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
}
```

El codigo del Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private boolean service_status=false;
private Button button;
private Intent intent;
private Servicio servicio=new Servicio();
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.content_main);
    intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Servicio.class);
    button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setText("Boton");
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (service_status) {
                button.setText("Desactivado");
                service_status=!service_status;
                stopService(intent);
            } else {
                button.setText("Activado");
                service_status=!service_status;
                startService(intent);
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

Ahora pasando a otro plano, si yo ejecuto la aplicacion el *button* tiene como texto inicial "Boton" y el *service_status* es igual a false; hago click en el boton, el servicio se inicia y el boton cambia de texto a "Activado" y el *service_status* cambia a true. Ahora cierro la aplicacion y la vuelvo a abrir. El *button* tiene como texto "Boton" y el *service_status* es false aunque el servicio ya esta ACTIVO¿Que codigo nesecito implementar para saber si el servicio esta activado y con eso cambiar el valor inicial del texto del *button* y del *service_status* al momento de iniciar la aplicacion?

Comment: Hola Math, bienvenido a [es.so], te sugiero completar el [tour] para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de [ask] para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad.

Comment: Hey Math , Puedes determinarlo mediante los métodos onStart() y onStop() del servicio, te sugiero obtengas más reputación para que puedas realizar este tipo de preguntas basadas en opiniones en [chat], saludos.